# How to save django model form, crispy, I cannot save the data to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

**Welcome friends**

I need your help.

I cannot save the data to my database from a form.

It may of course be very simple, but I don't know, how to do this.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    url(r'^busy/', views.product_busy, name='product_busy'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Busy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        verbose_name = 'busy'
        verbose_name_plural = 'busy'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('konfigurator:product_busy',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _, ugettext    
from crispy_forms import layout, bootstrap
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit, MultiField, Div, Field, Button
from .models import Busy

class Konfig(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Busy
        fields = ['name','slug']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Konfig, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_action = "."
        self.helper.form_method = "POST"
        self.helper.form_class = 'order-form'

        self.helper.layout = layout.Layout(
            layout.Fieldset(
                _("XXX"),
                layout.Field("name"),
                layout.Field("slug"),
            ),

            bootstrap.FormActions(
                layout.Submit("submit", _("Send"),
                             css_class="right"),
            )
        )
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Busy
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Konfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def product_list(request):
    return render(request,'konfig/product/list.html')

def product_busy(request):
    return render(request,'konfig/product/busy.html', {'form': Konfig()})

def konfig(request):
    form = Konfig()
    return render(request, "konfig/product/busy.html", {'form': form})
```

**busy.html**

```
{% extends "konfig/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy konfig_form konfig_form.helper %}

{% block title %}
    XX
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="order-info2">
        {% crispy form %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

How to solve a problem ?

I would appreciate your help.

UPDATE views.py

```
def konfig(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Konfig(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.save()
            name.save()
            name = Busy.objects.create(name=name)
            return render(request,
                          'konfig/product/busy.html',
                          {'name': name})
    else:
        form = Konfig()
    return render(request,
                  'konfig/product/busy.html',
                  {'form': form})
```

I try but it still does not work.
Maybe something with Context processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initialising your form, that's ok, but you are not accepting anything from the POST request.

It'd be better if you read more about http requests in django.

Anyway, I'd do something like this...

```
def konfig(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Konfig(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = Konfig()
    return render ( request, 'your_template', {'form':form})
```

Comment: It looks great. Unfortunately it does not work. Maybe something with Context processor. What do you think ?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?? Could you edit the post with the error message..

Comment: Also form.save() would suffice. The statements after that are completely unnecessary. The redirect to the url 'profile_busy' is wrong, bcz the url doesn't require any keyword arguments. kwargs{} is not needed.

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting an error. [12/May/2017 16:04:42] "POST /busy/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1822

Comment: Then, the data is written into the database, your template is also rendering. The only problem is in you syntax. Either redefine urls or views for better implementation.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help!

Comment: just do not know how to clean the form after posting. Reset the form. How do you do that Fazil?